# How twig support variable with space in url?

Tags: twig, slim

I have this code:

```
{% if  currentUrl() == siteUrl('/tag/' ~ tag) %}
    {% set pageTitle = tag %}
{% endif %}
```

when url is http://example.com/tag/test

page title is: test

but when url is http://example.com/tag/test test1

page title is: empty

How I can fix issue?

Thank you.

Comment: perfect url_encode working, Thank you

Comment: Cool. I moved my comment in an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult to answer because your issue is probably related to URL encodage and we don't know the `currentUrl()` and `siteUrl()` functions.

But, you can try to [`url_encode`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/url_encode.html) your tag, just in case:

```
{% if currentUrl() == siteUrl('/tag/' ~ tag|url_encode) %}
```

Comment: sorry, what isn't working? you mean that if your tag contains a +, this isn't working? I guess you can try using this kind of workaround to match all encoding issues at a glance: `{% if currentUrl() == siteUrl('/tag/' ~ tag) or currentUrl() == siteUrl('/tag/' ~ tag|url_encode) or currentUrl() == siteUrl('/tag/' ~ tag|url_encode(true)) %}` that's not really clean but your requirements looks really tricky.

Comment: I will use your code in search box when search 2 words together test test1 I will page title show test test1 code is {% if currentUrl() == siteUrl('/search?keyword=' ~ query) %}
    {% set pageTitle = query %}
{% endif %}

Comment: in browser we have this url after search http://localhost/search?keyword=test+test1